# Keep Getting A SQL Syntax Error

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, syntax-error

I've tried many things but for some reason I can not figure out why the following code keeps giving me an error.

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO app_users (signupDate, userToken, ipAddress, countryCode, countryName, regionName, cityName, zipCode, latitude, longitude, timeZone, referer, userAgent, hostName)
VALUES ('$ls_signupDate', '$ls_userToken', '$ls_ipAddress', '$ls_countryCode', '$ls_countryName', '$ls_regionName', '$ls_cityName', '$ls_zipCode', '$ls_latitude', '$ls_longitude', '$ls_timeZone', '$ls_referer', '$ls_userAgent', '$ls_hostName)'";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Content Inserted successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error inserting content: " . $conn->error;
}
```

The error it keeps giving me is...

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 2

**What am I doing wrong here?**

Comment: Take a close look at the very end of the `$sql` string.

Comment: Voting to close as a simple typo...

Comment: I must be an idiot.  I'm not seeing it.

Comment: `'$ls_hostName)'";` should be `'$ls_hostName')";`

Comment: OMG.. I AM an idiot!  Sorry.  I kinda wasted your time on this one... BUt thanks very much all the same.  I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should be as follows:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO app_users (signupDate, userToken, ipAddress, countryCode, countryName, regionName, cityName, zipCode, latitude, longitude, timeZone, referer, userAgent, hostName)
VALUES ('$ls_signupDate', '$ls_userToken', '$ls_ipAddress', '$ls_countryCode', '$ls_countryName', '$ls_regionName', '$ls_cityName', '$ls_zipCode', '$ls_latitude', '$ls_longitude', '$ls_timeZone', '$ls_referer', '$ls_userAgent', '$ls_hostName')";
```

Notice the order of single quote, parenthesis and double quotes.